# Google Appengine: My SQL Communications Link Failure from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Spring boot application connecting to gcloud sql (mysql) it works fine with public IP from my local machine, however when i deploy the app using appengine:deploy, it gives me a Communication link failure, I guess i am doing something wrong with my configuration. 
I have allowed appengine service account with role cloud sql client. 
and my configuration is

```
    spring:
  datasource: 
    url: jdbc:mysql://<PUBLIC IP>:3306/<DBNAME>
    username: rsadmin
    password: XXXXXX
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.database-name: <MYDBNAME>
spring.cloud.gcp.sql.instance-connection-name: <MYPROJECTID>:us-central1:<DBNAME>
```

Any helping would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome! are you using App Engine Standard or Flex? Perhaps you can take a look at the documentation for [connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#java) and [connecting to Cloud SQL from App Engine Flex](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible#java). Please don't forget to update your question to include your `app.yaml` file and any errors that you are receiving.

Comment: Hi I am using app Engine standard, another update is I am able to deploy the application on compute and it is working correct.

Comment: You will need to use the [JDBC socket factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_jdbc) to connect to Cloud SQL from your Java application. You will need to enable Cloud SQL Admin API in your project, as well as to install and authenticate the Cloud SDK before using the socket factory. Follow the instruction in the link above to add the library as a dependency and to create a JDBC URL.